# Why is the product of two norms is always bigger or equal to the norm of the same corresponding element?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

E.g. if $A$ is a matrix and $v$ is a vector which can be multiplied with the matrix, it always applies that (no matter how the norm is defined):

$||A|| ||v||\geq ||Av||$

Why is it so?

Comment: Do you know how one defines $\Vert A \Vert$?

Comment: I think all norms are equivalent.

Comment: Irrelevnt. Again, how do you define **this** norm?

Comment: I would like to know why does the relationship mentioned in my question applies for all norms, not any specific one.

Comment: It does not. $ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequality contains three norms: $\|A\|$, $\|v\|$ and $\|Av\|$. The last two are the norm of a vector, respectively $v$ and $Av$. You are right that you can use any norm here. But once you *decide* for one such norm then $\|A\|$ is *defined* by the formula

$$\|A\| = \max_{w\neq 0}{\frac{\|Aw\|}{\|w\|}}$$

i.e. the norm on matrices depends on the norm you had on vectors.

Comment: Where does the definition formula come from? Would you mind if you provide me further reading regarding this?

Comment: Well that's how it's normally defined. I suppose any book on linear algebra that covers normed vector spaces should cover it.